# nginx not returning Cache-Control header from upstream gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, whitenoise

I'm using [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) to serve static files from a Django app running under gunicorn. For some reason, the `Cache-Control` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers returned by the gunicorn backend are not being passed back to the client through the nginx proxy.

Here's what the response looks like for a sample request to the gunicorn backend:

```
% curl -I -H "host: www.myhost.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https" http://localhost:8000/static/img/sample-image.1bca02e3206a.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.8.1
Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2018 14:20:42 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 76640
Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 09:04:15 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000, public, immutable
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

When I make a request for the same file via the nginx server, the two headers are missing.

```
% curl -I -H "Host: www.myhost.com" -k https://my.server.com/static/img/sample-image.1bca02e3206a.jpg

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2018 14:09:25 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 76640
Last-Modified: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 09:04:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5b27758f-12b60"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

My nginx config is pretty much what is documented in the [gunicorn deployment docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html), i.e. I haven't enabled nginx caching (`nginx -T | grep -i cache` is empty) or done anything else I would think is out of the ordinary.

What am I missing?

Comment: does gunicorn actually get the request? can you see some sort of logs? maybe nginx just serves files himself? there is `location /` block in default config under your link.

Comment: You haven't enabled caching in Nginx and you want to know why it's not returning caching directives in it's response headers? A proxy server isn't just a pipe which your connection flows through unchanged to it's destination.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Yes! Thanks :-) I'm so used to defining a "location /static" in other scenarios that I assumed, because I had left it out, nginx was not handling the file. I forgot about "root"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}
```

directive in nginx config, so nginx just serves files himself and gunicorn doesn't even knows about it, and of course can't add headers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had forgotten the `root` directive I had configured many months ago, which was now picking up the static files. My error was in assuming that since I hadn't configured a `location /static` directive, nginx would be proxying all requests to the backend.

The solution for me was to remove the `$uri` reference from the `try_files` directive:

```
location / {
    try_files /dev/null @proxy_to_app;
}
```

Alternatively, I could have simply put the contents of the `@proxy_to_app` location block directly inside the `location /` block.

Thanks to Alexandr Tatarinov for the suggestion in the comments.